# Python overflow during calculation

Tags: python

I got a OverflowError: (34, 'Result too large') when i was calculating (-1 * w**(i+(n/2)) % p) when n = 256 using python. However, when i substituted n/2 with 128, Python could give me the answer without the error. Does anybody know what is the reason here?

Comment: Are `w`, `p`, `i`, and `n` integers? Is `n` always even?

Answer (score 0):

Because `float` objects, which will result from `/`, are fixed-size (64bit in most cases except exotic ones).

On the other hand, `int` objects are arbitrarily sized.

One possible solution is to use floor division, `//` which will result in result in an `int` when `n` is an `int`